# Не видит сайт при добавлении Nodejs Express.js на хостинг

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, hosting

загружаю проект на хостинг Hyberhost cPanel - NodeJs Express.js. Но вместо сайта показывает просто файлы. все настроила.
что сделала не так?

[image: Node.js]
[image: files]

Comment: Напишите им в тех. поддержку, они помогут, это их работа. Раз уж предоставляют услуги хостинга на для nodejs на express, то подскажут как правильно установить)

Answer (score 1):

Вам нужно [снять в аренду VPS](https://profitserver.ru/). Технически это как вечновключенный компьютер c доступом по [RDP если он на Windows](https://apps.microsoft.com/detail/9WZDNCRFJ3PS?hl=en-us&gl=US) и SSH если он на Linux

[image: filezilla]

Если сервак будет на Linux, используйте [FileZilla](https://filezilla-project.org/), чтобы удобно закинуть файлы проекта. Эта программа умеет кидать файлы как по FTP, так и SSH

```
tmux # открепить терминал от сессии SSH
tmux attach # подключиться к последней сессии после отключения
```

Чтобы NodeJS не был закрыт при отключении SSH, запустите его в [tmux](https://habr.com/en/articles/327630/). Если сервер на Windows то там тупо как на своем компе проект запускаете

Comment: Опробуйте WinSCP, мне кажется она куда удобнее)

Comment: пользуюсь digitalocean чтоб закинуть проект. но при deploy с github выскакивает ошибка:
> nodejs-blog@1.0.0 start
[2023-11-07 08:41:10] > app.js
[2023-11-07 08:41:10] 
[2023-11-07 08:41:10] sh: 1: app.js: not found 

Изза чего может быть?